# How to measure execution time of each thread in openmp?

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I'd like to measure the time that each thread spends doing a chunk of code. I'd like to see if my load balancing strategy equally divides chunks among workers.
Typically, my code looks like the following:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic,chunk) private(i)
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
//loop code here
}
```

UPDATE
I am using openmp 3.1 with gcc

Comment: What is your compiler (gcc/linux, icc, windows, macos) and openmp implementation? There are some openmp profilers/tracing solutions... Do you want to measure thread times in the each "for" loop, or you need only aggregated information about threads? (Why not add timer_start and timer_stop just around your "loop code here" with thread-local storage?)

Comment: This is more measuring the time that each thread spends to finish each chunk of iteration. Coding around the loop seems interesting, could you develop ?

Comment: You should use a performance analysis tool that explicitly supports OpenMP, like Score-P / Vampir, Allinea MAP, HPCToolkit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just print the per-thread time this way (not tested, not even compiled):

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    double wtime = omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp for schedule( dynamic, 1 ) nowait
    for ( int i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
        // whatever
    }
    wtime = omp_get_wtime() - wtime;
    printf( "Time taken by thread %d is %f\n", omp_get_thread_num(), wtime );
}
```

NB the `nowait`than removes the `barrier` at the end of the `for` loop, otherwise this wouldn't have any interest.

And of couse, using a proper profiling tool is a way better approach...

Comment: Worked just fine, just correct the lower case t in wtime. Thanks.